# Get image path in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any way to get the path of the last added image in a folder in Windows Form C#. I am stuck in that problem.

Comment: What do you actually understand when you say "last image that is added to the folder". First, what folder are you talking about?

Comment: You can watch folder for changes, see this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26528/C-Application-to-Watch-a-File-or-Directory-using-F

Comment: Why did you add `windows-forms-designer` to your tags??

Comment: I have just edit my description, sorry for bad expression, i dont write english regularly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\your directory name");
var myFile = directory.GetFiles()
         .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
         .First();
```

Enjoy!